# How to test a before_create that relies on a file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I have the following code in the model of my Rails app:

```
class Image
  before_create :choose_background   
  ...

  private

  def choose_background
    image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(self.image_path)
    background = ImageManipulator::get_background(image)
    self.background = background unless background.nil?
  end
end
```

Right now I just have these tests:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ImageTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should not save without a url" do
    image = Image.new
    assert !image.save
  end

end
```

`image_path` is a route to a path of an `Image`, and `ImageManipulator::get_background` basically does some image processing in order to find a background. So, my question is: How should I test this? Where/how should I place those images in order to test the method?

Answer (score 0):

Using FactoryGirl, I would create an Image with an image_path referring to an image file I place in /spec/fixtures/files

The test itself would look like

```
it "sets its background" do
  image = create(:image)
  expect(image.background).not_to be_nil
end
```

Comment: I am not using Rspec. I am using default Rails test framework.